# Shopify buy js sdk addLineItems null

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk, shopify-storefront-api

Im using shopify buy sdk to create checkout

I tried bellow

```
const lineItemsToAdd = [
                          variantId: 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8yOTEwNjAyMjc5Mg==',
                          quantity: 1
                        }
                    ];
const shippingAddress = {
                      address1: self.selectedAddress.address1,
                      address2: self.selectedAddress.address2,
                      city: self.selectedAddress.city,
                      company: null,
                      country: self.selectedAddress.country.country_language.name,
                      firstName: 'Bob',
                      lastName: 'Norman',
                      phone: self.selectedAddress.phone,
                      province:  self.selectedAddress.state.state_language.name,
                      zip: '11001'
                    };

await client.checkout.updateShippingAddress(checkoutData.id, shippingAddress);

 let mainCheckoutId = await client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutData.id, lineItemsToAdd);
```

Address works find but cannot add product to line items, it return null as bellow

`mainCheckoutId.lineItems = null`

Also erro msg

`userErrors retuns message ="Variant is invalid";`

I tried many products and all are published to online sale channel

And also im sure that variant id is correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed your issue, but it looks like you are missing a brace in lineItemsToAdd :

```
const lineItemsToAdd = [{variantId: 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8yOTEwNjAyMjc5Mg==', quantity: 1}];
```